# Find absolute minimum between two numpy arrays but keep the sign

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, difference

Consider two arrays of different length:

```
A = np.array([58, 22, 86, 37, 64])

B = np.array([105, 212,   5, 311, 253, 419, 123, 461, 256, 464])
```

For each value in `A`, I want to find the smallest absolute difference between values in `A` and `B`. I use `Pandas` because my actual arrays are subsets of Pandas dataframes but also because the `apply` method is a convenient (albeit slow) approach to taking the difference between two different-sized arrays:

```
In [22]: pd.Series(A).apply(lambda x: np.min(np.abs(x-B)))
Out[22]:
0    47
1    17
2    19
3    32
4    41
dtype: int64
```

**BUT** I also want to keep the sign, so the desired output is:

```
0    -47
1     17
2    -19
3     32
4    -41
dtype: int64
```

**[update]** my actual arrays `A` and `B` are approximately of 5e4 and 1e6 in length so a low memory solution would be ideal. Also, I wish to avoid using Pandas because it is very slow on the actual arrays.

Comment: If you are dealing with NumPy arrays, where does pandas come in?

Comment: @cs95 you're correct, pandas isn't needed. I forgot about NumPy's broadcasting so wasn't sure how to subtract different-sized arrays without recourse to Pandas and the `apply` method.

Comment: Can you have two output columns: one for the `absdiff` (which you can then easily do min on), and one for the `sign`? or else do you just need to broadcast a `min_abs_diff_preserve_sign` pandas/numpy function?

Comment: *"I use Pandas because my actual arrays are subsets of Pandas dataframes"* Well if they're `pandas Series` not `numpy arrays`, please edit the title to say so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Comprehension

I couldn't help myself.  This is not what you should do!  But, it is cute.

```
[min(x - B, key=abs) for x in A]

[-47, 17, -19, 32, -41]
```

---

#### Reduced Big-O Numpy solution

If `N = len(A)` and `M = len(B)` then this solution should be `O(N + M log(M))`
If `B` is already sorted, then the sorting step is unnecessary. and this becomes `O(N + M)`

```
C          = np.sort(B)
a          = C.searchsorted(A)

# It is possible that `i` has a value equal to the length of `C`
# in which case the searched value exceeds all those found in `C`.
# In that case, we want to clip the index value to the right most index
# which is `len(C) - 1`
right      = np.minimum(a, len(C) - 1)

# For those searched values that are less than the first value in `C`
# the index value will be `0`.  When I subtract `1`, we'll end up with
# `-1` which makes no sense.  So we clip it to `0`.
left       = np.maximum(a - 1, 0)
```

For clipped values, we'll end up comparing a value to itself and therefore it is safe.

```
right_diff = A - C[right]
left_diff  = A - C[left ]

np.where(np.abs(right_diff) <= left_diff, right_diff, left_diff)

array([-47,  17, -19,  32, -41])
```

Comment: On my actual arrays, `left_diff = A-C[left]` errors out because of an `IndexError`. Namely, say if array C is of length 100 and `left` returns index 100 then it'll err out (since indexed 0-99). Would `left = np.maximum(a,0) - 1` preserve the algorithm and fix the indexing issue?

Comment: @GeneBurinsky apologies.  I updated my post.  It should be `np.maximum(a - 1, 0)`  Don't use `np.maximum(a, 0) - 1` because that will break in the instance the minimum value happens in the first position as the corresponding position will be `-1`.

Answer (score 5):

Let's use broadcasted subtraction here. We then use `argmin` to find the absolute minimum, then extract the values in a subsequent step.

```
u = A[:,None] - B
idx = np.abs(u).argmin(axis=1)

u[np.arange(len(u)), idx]
# array([-47,  17, -19,  32, -41])
```

This uses pure NumPy broadcasting, so it should be quite fast.

Comment: This is a fast but very memory intensive solution. It's good for smaller arrays but on my actual data, I run into `MemoryError`. For perspective, my actual `A` is of length 50e3 and `B` is 1e6 so the memory requirement for a broadcast are humongous.

Answer (score 2):

`np.argmin` can find the position of the minimum value. Therefore you can simply do this:

```
pd.Series(A).apply(lambda x: x-B[np.argmin(np.abs(x-B))])
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged `pandas`:

```
# compute the diff by broadcasting
diff = pd.DataFrame(A[None,:] - B[:,None])
# mininum value
min_val = diff.abs().min()

# mask with where and stack to drop na
diff.where(diff.abs().eq(min_val)).stack()
```

Output:

```
0  0   -47.0
   2   -19.0
   4   -41.0
2  1    17.0
   3    32.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: If you would like using pandas `s=pd.DataFrame(A[None,:] - B[:,None]);
s.lookup(s.abs().idxmin(),s.columns)
Out[123]: array([-47,  17, -19,  32, -41])
`